# how to config spring boot global output the result formatter

Tags: java, spring

I want to to find a global return formatter in spring boot.
for example:

controller method return String,

```
{String}
```

but I want to output follow json

```
{
code:200,
message:success,
data:String
}
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just create a class with a field "code" (that is an int for instance), a field message and a field data. Then, if you return the object it will be automaticaly marshalled by your springboot controller.

Then you pack it in an object ResponseEntity so your return type is a generic type ResponseEntity.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getStuff() {
    MyObject result = new MyObject("200", "success", "My Cuty Message");
    return new ResponseEntity<MyObject>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: thank you,I am a Chinese, for the first time here to get your answer

Comment: Thank  you satya-j for correcting the typo myObject to entity :), I copy past a bit quickly and i missed it...